# vue, как прокинуть функция в prop?

Tags: vue.js

Как сделать так, что бы прокинуть функцию в prop, и там ее вызвать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно также как и любой другой объект. Для этого функция должны быть методом/свойством в data/computed-свойством компонента, который будет прокидывать ее как prop.

В родительском компоненте:

```
<child-component :func="func" />
...
methods: {
  func () {
   // код функции
  }
}
```

В дочернем компоненте:

```
props: {
  func: {
    type: Function
  }
}
methods: {
  child_func () {
   // вызов функции из prop, желательно убедиться, что не пусто там
   this.func()
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли.